# Authentication for Java Rally Rest API

Tags: web-services, rest, authentication, oauth, rally

I need to integrate my web application with Rally. Using Rest Rally API(Java), though I am able to create a User story from a stand alone program hardcoding my APIKey. But how do i create it using oauth authentication in java. I did get that through oauth authentication, we will get an access token. but how do i make use of that access token for using Rally rest API since, it accepts either API Key or userName/pwd for that. Any help on authentication will be appreciated. Thanking in advance.

```
String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";

RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI(host), "my_APIKey-XXXXXX");

//  Creating a User Story
JsonObject newStory = new JsonObject();
newStory.addProperty("Name", "test User Story");
newStory.addProperty("Project", projectRef);
newStory.addProperty("Workspace",workspaceRef);
newStory.addProperty("Iteration", iterationRef);
newStory.addProperty("Release", releaseRef);
newStory.addProperty("Description", "Test Description");
newStory.addProperty("Notes", "test Notes");
newStory.addProperty("c_AcceptanceCriteria","Test acceptance criteria");

CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("hierarchicalrequirement", newStory);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rally Rest Toolkit for Java does not currently support OAuth/SSO.  API Keys are the best way forward currently.

Comment: Thanks for the response Kyle. So, I believe, till the support for oauth is rolled out, I need to hardcode the API Key of any of the team member of my project for using Rally Rest Toolkit. Can you let me know, is there any plan to roll out oauth support for this? If so, when is that planned?